# Why can't I see image in design view but can see it in browser?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I can see my menubar when I preview webpage in browser but I cannot see it in Dreamweaver design view?

Here is my code incase there is a mistake
CSS;

```
#bar {  
  margin-top:5%;
  background:url("/Users/Macbook/Desktop/test website/images/bar.png") no-repeat center; 
  height:50px;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

HTML;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="Untitled-3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="bar">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Dreamweaver is not reliable for this

Comment: Sorry what do you mean, usually when i create any page, a preview is available in the design view, ?

Comment: can you to add this plz in #bar css    background:red;  you can view red box ?

Comment: Yes when i change it to that i can see the box in design view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your image path is not good

when you work for web,

attempts to your organization like this

```
-root folder
----img folder
----css folder
----js folder
```

etc, etc (it's just an exemple)
in your case try this

```
-root folder
    index.html
----img (contain bar.png)
----css (contain Untitled-3.css)
```

dont forget to replace path  in html for css :

```
<link href="css/Untitled-3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and of course in css :

```
background:url("../img/bar.png") no-repeat center;
```

try this : )

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you begin a URL with a slash, it's essentially an absolute path.  It says "start at the domain root and go from there".

I can't explain why it's working in the browser but not in Dreamweaver - but if you change the path to `images/bar.png` or even try `/images/bar.png`, it should start working again.